# Polynomial coefficients of $f(x) = \frac{1}{100} e^{5x} - \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: functions, exponential-function, elementary-functions

Can anybody tell me what the polynomial coefficients are for this function?

$f(x) = \frac{1}{100} e^{5x} - \frac{1}{4}$

I'm just trying to get the function coefficient vector and then use "roots" function in Scilab to get polynomial root.

When I have simple fuction like this: $$f(x) = x^2 + x - 1$$
then I know that my function coefficient vector is:
$[1,1,-1]$.

Comment: Are you asking for the power series? Edit:   It will be an infinite power series, not a finite polynomial

Comment: If you want to solve $$\displaystyle\frac{1}{100}e^{5x} - \frac{1}{4} = 0$$

then you can add $1/4$ to both sides, then multiply everything by $100$. You get $$e^{5x} = 25$$

Now, take the natural log of both sides:

$$\ln \left(e^{5x}\right) = \ln(25)$$

$$5x = \ln(5^2)$$

$$x = \boxed{\frac{2 \ln 5}{5}\,}$$

Comment: To answer the exact question you asked: your $f(x)$ is not a polynomial, so asking for its polynomial coefficients does not make sense.

Comment: It's not a polynomial, so we can't speak of polynomial coefficient  Are you interested in its Taylor series

(-6/25)+x/20+x^2/8+(5*x^3)/24+(25*x^4)/96+(25*x^5)/96+(125*x^6)/576+..........
 Which is an infinite polynomial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying fo find a solution to a general non-linear equation, then you can use `fsolve`:

```
function y=f(x)
    y=exp(5*x)/100 -1/4
end

x=fsolve(1,f)

--> disp(x)

   0.6437752
```

Answer (score 0):

The exponential function $e^x$ is *trascendental* (not algebraic, i.e., not expressible exactly as a polynomial, a ratio of polynomials, or roots of the above). So are the logarithm and trigonometric functions (elementary trascendental functions). You can't get the coefficients as a polynomial for your function, as it is not a polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a polynomial, so we can't speak of polynomial coefficient

Are you interested in its Taylor series

$\frac{-6}{25}+\frac{x}{20}+\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{5*x^3}{24}+\frac{25*x^4}{96}+\frac{25*x^5}{96}+\frac{125*x^6}{576}+..........$